# I got a shock from the soldering iron

Tags: soldering, soldering-iron-station

I bought a soldering iron from market. I used it for about 15 minutes and it worked great, but after that, when I touched the soldering wire to the tip of the soldering iron, I got a threatening shock. Can anybody tell me what happened?

Comment: Hello, welcome to EESE. 
It sounds like you might be having a chassis short from inside the iron.  Since you don't list what kind of iron you have, I can't be sure.
I will also say that this stack exchange is more so for electronics design and not electronics repair.

Comment: Many things could have happened, but it pops my mind... The wire you were soldering was connected to something? If it was, and the iron doesn't have proper grounding or you didn't connect to a properly grounded plug, there could be a leak current through the wire. Also, even with the wire not connected to a source of current, the ground issue could be it. Of course, the iron could be just deffective and doesn't have properly isolation inside, leading to current flow through the tip.

Comment: Typical of Wun Hung Lo junk...

Comment: Yeah, even Long Duck Dong stuff is hit or miss.

Answer (score 8):

Argh. The answer depends on whether it has a 3-wire (grounded) plug or two-wire.

If the former, then your wiring is bad (ground is not properly grounded), and the soldering iron is probably okay.

If it is two-wire then the soldering iron has a dangerous short and you should not use it, and immediately return it for a refund. You can check by measuring with an ohmmeter between the input power (not ground) and the tip. You do that with the power disconnected, obviously, but it might only show up when the tip is hot, so you can allow it to heat then pull the plug and test it.

Some of the crappiest soldering irons are something like 50-60 cents US in quantity, so I'm not surprised there might be some quality issues.

Comment: It has a 3 wire plug.

Comment: Then check for continuity between the ground pin and tip. If it's connected, then your wall plug wiring is dangerously bad. If it's not connected, then the soldering iron is dangerously defective.

Comment: One way to test for this is to take it to your kitchen and plug it into a GFCI outlet.

Comment: @SDsolar, that's a region specific suggestion. In Europe all house sockets will be on RCD / GFCI.

Comment: I got the same issue (small shocks) while soldering, and after checking the electric installation, it appears that it's not grounded at all. Thanks for the answer, it helped a lot.